# How to differentiate between app crashing and user closing

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to run code conditionally on whether the user closed the app or the app crashed.

The `session$onSessionEnded` runs regardless of how the session ended. And I did not find some other function or variable inside `session` that looked like it could be an indicator on how the session ended.

Basically I would like to use something similar to the commented code in the sample app below. Where `crashed` would be printed if I click the button, but `user ended` would be printed if I close the app (eg, close the browser).

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(actionButton('crash', 'crash me'))
server <- function(input, output, session){
  observeEvent(input$crash, stop())
  session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    # if (crashed){
    #   print('crashed')
    # }else{
    #   print('user ended')
    # }
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `shiny.error` option to define a custom error handler.

Try:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(actionButton('crash', 'crash me'))

errorfn <- function() {crashed <<- T }
options(shiny.error = errorfn)
crashed <- F

server <- function(input, output, session){

  session$userData$starttime <- Sys.time()
  observeEvent(input$crash, stop())
  session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    if (crashed) print(paste("Started at :",session$userData$starttime, " - Crashed at : " , Sys.time())) else print("Not crashed, ended by user")
    stopApp(crashed)
    crashed <<- F
  })
}
runApp(list(ui=ui, server=server))

[1] "Started at : 2020-09-15 17:27:41  - Crashed at :  2020-09-15 17:27:45"
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Nice approach, didn't think to register a custom error function, but it doesn't quite solve the problem. Using a global variable for tracking whether the app crashed or not means you can only check it for one user (I guess that's why you're using stopApp as well?). Also, the custom error function triggers when errors occur in output blocks, which don't actually crash the application.

Comment: I used `stopApp()` because in interactive mode in RStudio I still have to stop the App after UI crash. `stopApp()` avoids this. I think error handling stays a promising way, and you're right the current solution is for single user in development environment. However, the global variable could be a list of all the client crashes with the session$user who caused this : should I elaborate on this in my answer? If the server really crashes, I doubt `session$onSessionEnded` will work.

Comment: I see. It would be great if you could elaborate on how to make it work for multiple sessions. I was just playing with your example app and it seemed that the `session` object is not available inside `errorfn`, so I'm curious to see how you would create this list.

Comment: See my edit : you can store session relevant info in `session$userData` and use it to make a report on the crash, and then reset the global variable. Should cover most crashes.

Comment: @bobbel, did you try the `session$UserData` option to allow user dependent handling?

Comment: Yes, this'll work. I don't think it's ideal to use a global boolean with `<<-` assignment, but it should solve my problem,so I guess I shouldn't be complaining.

Comment: @bobbel, unfortunately this didn't work with a boolean in the server function... Perhaps someone will come up with a more elegant solution, but at least we're a step further ;)